# Reactive data just once and then stock it globally in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm trying to develop with R Shiny, I ask the user to do 5 file inputs. And then I have a reactive function ***mergeFun()*** which will cast and merge the data in one data set once the inputs are done.

Then I have multiple buttons, boxplots, renderUI, outputs, PCA, regression trees,... in my different tabPanels and each one of these calls the function ***mergeFun()*** in order to do the statistic analysis.

So as it is making quite some time after the inputs to load everyone of these panels at once, I was wondering if there was a way to just call the function globally and stock the merged data in one global variable.

I was thinking maybe because I call this function x times once in each analysis in the tabPanels, it was causing the time lapse.
So I would just be able to call the data instead of calling the function ***mergeFun()***

I'm posting the code modified, to give you an idea about what I am doing

```
mergeFun <- reactive({
#So there I had my test about if my files existed
#I delete for visibility

cast <- dcast(input,var1 + var2,value.var = "var3")

mergeAll <- merge(input2,cast,by=c("var1","var2","var3"))

data.frame(mergeAll)

})
```

So this is my ***mergeFun()*** and then I have many reactive and renderUI which will all start like this :

```
output$xcol <- renderUI({
df <-mergeFun()
if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
...
...
...
})
```

So maybe calling mergeFun() x times isn't programatically efficient?

Comment: Please provide a minimal and *complete* reproducible example.

Comment: Even though you have a reactive called `mergeFun()`, it isn't really a function.  It's a recipe for how to create an object.  `mergeFun()` is only be triggered when any of its outputs are invalidated.  Once it is finished updating, `mergeFun()` can be used like an object: no matter how many times you call it in your code, it will not run again until one of its inputs changes.  It is unlikely that calling it multiple times is what causes your application to be slow.  It may just be that `mergeFun()` takes a while to update, or something else entirely.

Comment: Alright then, yes maybe the merge and the cast are just taking a while with all the datas I have,